# "I play soccer more than I think I"

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

> I play soccer more than I think I do.

and

> I play soccer more than he.

are acceptable, but I wonder if

> I play soccer more than I think I

is also acceptable.

Comment: No. Not acceptable. The 'do' is required. You could omit 'I do' altogether: _I play soccer more than I think_, although the sentence is nonsense. You can _possibly_, or _probably_, do something more than you think you do, but how do you know for sure?

Comment: It would *technically* be correct to say, "I play soccer more than I[,] think I", but that makes even less sense than your original sentence. And this kind of subject-verb inversion ("think I", here meaning "I think") is no longer used in everyday speech.

Answer (score 1):

WIthout the verb it's just a fragment. Drop the "I".

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work.

"I play soccer more than he" is a comparison. I play more. More than whom or what? More than he.

"I play soccer more than I" is, I suppose, grammatically correct but doesn't make any sense. I play more. More than whom? More than myself. How could you play more than yourself?

"I play soccer more than I think I do" is a different sort of comparison. I play soccer more. More than what? More than I think I do. That's also a rather illogical statement. You're saying that you think you play soccer more than you think you play soccer. How is that possible? It would make sense to say, "Bob plays soccer more than he thinks he does", but I don't see how you could rationally say that about yourself. Maybe if you said, "I wonder if I play soccer more than I think I do" or "Maybe I play soccer more than I think I do", that would make sense. But whatever, I suppose I'm supposed to be discussing grammar and not logic.

"I play soccer more than I think I" is an incomplete sentence. More than I think I what? You have a subject with no verb.

Comment: "I play soccer more than he" is non-idiomatic even though it may be grammatically correct (and i'm not entirely sure that it is). Much more common are "I play soccer more than he _does_" and "I play soccer more than _him_", even if some people would contend that the second one is grammatically incorrect. I personally think that the accusative form is correct, the third person pronoun is the indirect object of the verb "to play".

Comment: @BoldBen True. I probably should have discussed this. "I play soccer more than he" is an abbreviated version of "I play soccer more than he does". "... more than him" is also valid: the preposition takes the objective case.